# Unable to resolve dependencies for Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-universal

I need to use SSR for one of my existing angular project. For that, I have migrated one of my projects from v8 to v13.0.0, which itself took a lot of time.

HOwever, now that the app is running fine on v13.0.0, I tried adding SSR to it using

> ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

This commands seems to add 13.0.1 of universal, but it keeps failing with errors similar to below one:

> D:\my-app-universal>ng add @nguniversal/express-engine i Using package
> manager: npm √ Found compatible package version:
> @nguniversal/express-engine@13.0.1. √ Package information loaded.
>
> The package @nguniversal/express-engine@13.0.1 will be installed and
> executed. Would you like to proceed? Yes npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm
> ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR! npm ERR!
> While resolving: my-app-universal@0.0.0 npm ERR! Found:
> @angular/animations@13.0.3 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
> npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~13.0.0" from the root project npm
> ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> @angular/animations@"13.2.3" from @angular/platform-server@13.2.3 npm
> ERR! node_modules/@angular/platform-server npm ERR!   peer
> @angular/platform-server@"^13.0.1" from
> @nguniversal/express-engine@13.0.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine npm ERR!
> @nguniversal/express-engine@"13.0.1" from the root project npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
> ERR! See
> C:\Users\saurabhtiwari\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for
> a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\saurabhtiwari\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-20T12_03_46_821Z-debug.log
> × Package install failed, see above.

I have tried a lot to read through the errors and updating package.json to match the required version of peers but it just doesn't go away.

Is there a systematic way to resolve these errors.
Is there a particular version of universal that might go well with Angular 13.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: First try ng add ... --force if that fails try to npm install --force instead of ng add

Comment: Try this `install --save --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: @misha130 npm install ... --force seems to have succeeded, while I had already tried --force with ng add and that didn't work. Can you please explain the difference. ?

Comment: @misha130 npm install ... --force didn't throw any error. However, it didn't add the required express server and other files as I was expecting.

Comment: Try to delete node_module folder, then re run command npm install and then try to add SSR ng add

Comment: --force disregards the peer dependencies when installing. Without force it checks the other library versions and see if they match up. Basically the ultimate solution is to lower other package versions or raise them. To do this you need to carefully read the error and do it quite a few times

Answer (score 7):

I followed @misha130's comments advice and fixed the version numbers.  I didn't need to need to install with `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force`.

The solution was to upgrade `@angular/cli` & `@angular/core`.

With a fresh install, my initial version was `13.0.4`.  You will need to upgrade them one at a time as the update command fails if there are staged and uncommitted changes in the repository.

```
ng update @angular/cli

git add . && git commit -m 'nguniversal fix 1 - update @angular/cli'

ng update @angular/core

git add . && git commit -m 'nguniversal fix 2 - update @angular/core'

ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

Comment: Bless you. This is precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone for their inputs in the comment. I figured it out as below.

As suggested in comments, first I installed the universal package using --legacy --per --deps

```
npm install @nguniversal/express-engine --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

This installed the packages in the node_modules, although the required express-server related files were not added.

To add those files, I then ran:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

This creates the required file. It will also try to install the package again and will fail in doing so. Since the package have been installed already, I guess you can ignore its error.